# Multiplication of cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

When we multiply cycles, do we keep multiplying until we get two disjoint cycles? Or is the final product supposed to be obtained in one step?

An example is

α=(1 2 3)(4 5)(1 6 7 8 9)(1 5)

= (1 4 5 6 7 8 9)(2 3 1 4 5 6 7 8 9)

= (1 5 7 9 2 3 4 6 8)

Is this right?

Comment: The answer will be a product of disjoint cycles. Since the multiplication is associative you can arrive at the answer in many correct ways. If you are still confused, [edit] the question to show us an example that puzzles you and why.

Comment: I've added an example. I'm not sure if the steps are correct.

Comment: Are you 'multiplying' permutations (which is function composition) left-to-right or right-to-left?

Comment: Your initial calculation is wrong. Check what happens to $9$. It goes to $1$ and then to $2$, so the first cycle in your answer does not close where you say it does.

Comment: One way is to calculate $\alpha(1), \alpha(\alpha(1)), \alpha(\alpha(\alpha(1))), \ldots$ until you get back to $1$. This gives you one of the disjoint cycles. If there is a $k$ that doesn't appear in this cycle, then calculate $\alpha(k), \alpha(\alpha(k)), \alpha(\alpha(\alpha(k))), \ldots$ until you get back to $k$, giving you another disjoint cycle. Repeat until all numbers appear in one of the cycles. It looks like you have started trying to do this , but miscalculated $\alpha(9)$. If you get it right, the cycles will automatically come out disjoint.

Comment: I got it. Thank you all!